# Only One Update Function Working PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to have a button that updates a value and changes it to "HIGH" and another to update the same value and change it to "LOW". Both functions work individually, but when in the same file only the one whose input comes first works. This may sound confusing. If you look at the code below, you can see there are two inputs. If the on function is called by the second input, it works. If it is called by the second input function it does not.

```
<?php

function off(){
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("arduino");
    mysql_query("UPDATE `leds` SET `state` = 'LOW' WHERE `id` = 13");
}

function on(){
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("arduino");
    mysql_query("UPDATE `leds` SET `state` = 'HIGH' WHERE `id` = 13");
}



?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" value = "Turn On" onclick = "<?php on(); ?>">
<br />
    <br />
    <input type = "button" value = "Turn Off" onclick = "<?php off(); ?>">
</body>
</html>
```

I am very confused by this. Anyone know what is going on. If I have not been clear enough please say so and I would be glad to provide more detail.

Comment: Actually, it's the second one that should work here. You expect the server-side to work on the client-side, but that's not what happens here: both functions are executed when you invoke them at the server-side, and the one that's called the last should win that race.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible for the reason raina77ow outlines above - PHP runs on server side, JavaScript runs in the browser, and conditions inside JavaScript don't apply to PHP

Comment: @raina77ow: That is correct; I miswrote...thank you for correcting me

Comment: What you need is to make two separate actions (one for `on`, another for `off`), and call these actions with POST method (via AJAX, most probably).

Comment: Future improvement: Don't quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work for the reason raina77ow and Pekka pointed out.

But this might:

HTML(cliente-side):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function set(bit_status){
    $.get('handle.php', {status: bit_status});
}
</script>
<input type = "button" value = "Turn On" onclick="set('HIGH')">
<br />
    <br />
    <input type = "button" value = "Turn Off" onclick="set('LOW'">
</body>
</html>
```

PHP(server-side) handle.php file:

```
function off(){
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("arduino");
    mysql_query("UPDATE `leds` SET `state` = 'LOW' WHERE `id` = 13");
}

function on(){
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("arduino");
    mysql_query("UPDATE `leds` SET `state` = 'HIGH' WHERE `id` = 13");
}

$status = $_GET['status'];
if($status == 'HIGH') on();
else off();
```

Comment: I figured out an alternative way but thanks for putting so much effort into your response. I will mark it as answer; that looks like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your input tags is inside a form, and neither of them is closed either. I am not sure if that is the problem, but it does not help.